# JS files landing on page but not working, using childtheme of twentyeleven

Tags: javascript

my functions.php from child theme, does not seem to allow the script to run in the page, it works on the styles using @import url. do I need to do something like that with the Javascript or is there maybe a conflict with other scripts in the main theme.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

With the style.css, we are mentioning like that the theme is a child of some existing theme. So the css file is enough to render all parent theme functionalities.
We are using all other files to add or alter the existing theme features.

we have to include the following basic things in child css file

```
 /*
Theme Name: Your Custom Theme
Description: The simple and powerful theme.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: twentyeleven

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

You first remove all files in child theme except the style.css and check whether the default theme features rendering or not.If no, then it is the problem with our style.css.

Also, if any custom css / js file needed, it is better to create them in a separate folder within our child theme itself and call them through our child functions.php file.

Please give us the code that you made in style.css and functions.php

Comment: Hi Asha, I have added the code to Paste bin, I did try to include them in my original post but must have made some mistake when posting. I am working in Instant-WP as my site is live for usability testing at the moment. I have created it in Html/Javascript as I did not think it would be suitable for wordpress originally. It was only when I created the shop I realised it would be better in wordpress. I need to add in seperate javascript to 12 pages. . The pastebin address is:http://pastebin.com/Vpxcg3Nw